# Is there a way in javascript/jQuery to perminantly store data?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-plugins

Is there? I don't know. I've been hitting my head against a brick wall with ways to possibly do this *without* using a server-side language.

So far my code runs well locally as well as on a server - I'd rather not have to use a server-side language.

Well, there's the challenge. First one with a correct answer wins.... uh... points.

*(Oh, and I'm not asking for code examples before anyone flames me - just a simple nod in the right direction would be grand)*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cookies or HTML5 databases. The latter has the benefit of not adding overhead to every network request you make, and it's managed separately from cookies and responds to a query language, rather than a simple key value store.

Answer (score 2):

There is a good solution I'm using currently for persistence, it's a jQuery plugin called jStore with nice and easy api. Here it is http://twablet.com/docs.html?p=jstore

It supports all modern browsers and even can fall back to flash-based storage option. So it's fully transparent for you to write your code putting and popping up your data by key. It's basically a key-value persistent storage.

Answer (score 1):

depending on how much data you are looking to store, you can store it in a cookie.

Answer (score 0):

html5 gets a local storage db called [webstorage](http://dev.w3.org/html5/webstorage/) this is already implemented in cromium and in safari. Very small amounts of data could also be stored in a cookie